# How do I run a ggboxplot in ggplotly within R Markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, ggplotly, ggpubr

## Problem:

I'm not sure what is going on, but every time I try to run this in my R script, I get no issues. When I run it in R Markdown, it produces errors despite pre-loading all of the necessary packages and data. I will list the error below. First, I will show what I have for a script.

Here is the dput for my data:

```
structure(list(Case_Number = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 
22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 
35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 
48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 
62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 
75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 
88L, 89L, 90L, 91L), Year = c("2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", 
"2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", 
"2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", 
"2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", 
"2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", 
"2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", 
"2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", 
"2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", 
"2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", 
"2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", 
"2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", 
"2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021"), Month_Number = c("9", 
"9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", 
"9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", 
"9", "9", "9", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", 
"10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", 
"10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", 
"11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", 
"11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", 
"11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11"), Month_Name = c("September", 
"September", "September", "September", "September", "September", 
"September", "September", "September", "September", "September", 
"September", "September", "September", "September", "September", 
"September", "September", "September", "September", "September", 
"September", "September", "September", "September", "September", 
"September", "September", "September", "September", "October", 
"October", "October", "October", "October", "October", "October", 
"October", "October", "October", "October", "October", "October", 
"October", "October", "October", "October", "October", "October", 
"October", "October", "October", "October", "October", "October", 
"October", "October", "October", "October", "October", "November", 
"November", "November", "November", "November", "November", "November", 
"November", "November", "November", "November", "November", "November", 
"November", "November", "November", "November", "November", "November", 
"November", "November", "November", "November", "November", "November", 
"November", "November", "November", "November", "November"), 
    Day_Number = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
    12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
    24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
    7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
    19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
    15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 
    27L, 28L, 29L, 30L), Day_Name = c("Wednesday", "Thursday", 
    "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
    "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", 
    "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", 
    "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", 
    "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", 
    "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", 
    "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
    "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", 
    "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", 
    "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", 
    "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", 
    "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", 
    "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", 
    "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
    "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday"
    ), Time_Wake = c(500L, 715L, 600L, 600L, 700L, 600L, 700L, 
    500L, 500L, 500L, 500L, 700L, 645L, 700L, 630L, 645L, 700L, 
    600L, 700L, 550L, 700L, 730L, 725L, 800L, 600L, 640L, 600L, 
    730L, 650L, 830L, 630L, 630L, 830L, 722L, 641L, 800L, 720L, 
    700L, NA, NA, NA, 700L, 700L, 622L, 710L, 632L, 400L, 640L, 
    700L, 730L, 830L, 659L, 800L, 701L, 700L, 900L, 930L, 650L, 
    930L, NA, 300L, 830L, 800L, 705L, 647L, 800L, NA, 830L, NA, 
    830L, 838L, 650L, 849L, 500L, 830L, 800L, 321L, 700L, 400L, 
    400L, NA, 700L, 600L, 604L, 700L, 730L, 700L, 700L, 500L, 
    700L), Mins_Sleep = c(300L, 540L, 540L, 480L, 480L, 480L, 
    480L, 420L, 300L, 240L, 480L, 300L, 420L, 360L, 390L, 405L, 
    420L, 360L, 420L, 350L, 420L, 450L, 445L, 480L, 300L, 400L, 
    310L, 390L, 350L, 450L, 390L, 390L, 510L, 452L, 310L, 360L, 
    500L, 360L, NA, NA, 420L, 420L, 420L, 382L, 430L, 393L, 240L, 
    400L, 480L, 450L, 450L, 359L, 420L, 361L, 360L, 480L, 570L, 
    340L, 450L, NA, 180L, 510L, 420L, 425L, 407L, 360L, NA, 510L, 
    NA, 360L, 368L, 410L, NA, 360L, 510L, 436L, 291L, 420L, 240L, 
    300L, NA, 420L, 420L, 424L, 520L, 240L, 390L, 480L, 300L, 
    480L), Start_Work = c(1015L, 1000L, 945L, 1400L, 1500L, 915L, 
    930L, 1000L, 940L, 840L, 730L, 1700L, 945L, 1040L, 955L, 
    945L, 930L, 745L, 800L, 955L, 1030L, 1115L, 905L, 930L, 815L, 
    830L, 950L, 1108L, 1430L, 955L, 1313L, 1125L, 1636L, 1126L, 
    1027L, 1323L, 1003L, 918L, NA, NA, 950L, 913L, 1244L, 656L, 
    930L, 718L, 1744L, 759L, 928L, 912L, 857L, 930L, 907L, 920L, 
    1029L, 1027L, 1211L, 914L, 1226L, 1337L, 1900L, 1313L, 1118L, 
    800L, 700L, 1544L, 1350L, 905L, 1025L, 0L, 942L, 930L, 1234L, 
    1222L, 925L, 0L, 2018L, 945L, 500L, 447L, 0L, 818L, 604L, 
    632L, 1015L, 930L, 748L, 732L, 900L, 739L), End_Work = c(1800L, 
    1600L, 1210L, 1700L, 1515L, 1530L, 1530L, 1800L, 1650L, 1800L, 
    1410L, 2000L, 1710L, 1430L, 1800L, 1840L, 1720L, 1915L, 1240L, 
    2040L, 1730L, 1825L, 1100L, 2130L, 1705L, 915L, 1504L, 1430L, 
    1933L, 1335L, 1330L, 2130L, 1636L, 1600L, 1730L, 1800L, 1739L, 
    1413L, NA, NA, 1729L, 2200L, 2219L, 2316L, 2359L, 911L, 2014L, 
    1945L, 2113L, 2004L, 2017L, 1530L, 2114L, 2158L, 1800L, 1813L, 
    2005L, 1717L, 1512L, 1620L, 2209L, 2200L, 1231L, 2030L, 1817L, 
    1737L, 1605L, 2038L, 2357L, 2348L, 1407L, 1653L, 1720L, 1927L, 
    2359L, 1911L, 2355L, 1726L, 2247L, 2359L, 2020L, 2032L, 1818L, 
    1449L, 1407L, 1330L, 2223L, 2232L, 2040L, 2359L), Workout_Y_N = c(1, 
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Time_Workout = c(730L, 
    730L, 730L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 730L, 730L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 735L, 
    735L, 735L, NA, NA, 2030L, 730L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    730L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 915L, 1000L, 815L, NA, 900L, 740L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1011L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Work_Environment = c("Office", 
    "Office", "Office", "Home", "Home", "Office", "Office", "Office", 
    "Office", "Office", "Home", "Home", "Office", "Office", "Office", 
    "Home", "Office", "Home", "Home", "Office", "Office", "Home", 
    "Office", "Home", "Home", "Home", "Office", "Office", "Office", 
    "Office", "Home", "Home", "Home", "Office", "Office", "Office", 
    "Office", "Office", "Home", "Home", "Office", "Both", "Home", 
    "Home", "Both", "Home", "Home", "Both", "Office", "Home", 
    "Home", "Both", "Home", "Home", "Office", "Office", "Home", 
    "Office", "Home", "Home", "Home", "Both", "Home", "Both", 
    "Both", "Home", "Home", "Both", "Both", "Home", "Home", "Office", 
    "Office", "Home", "Both", "Both", "Home", "Office", "Both", 
    "Home", "Home", "Both", "Both", "Home", "Home", "Both", "Home", 
    "Home", "Office", "Both"), Coffee_Cups = c(3L, 0L, 2L, 6L, 
    4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    4L, 4L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 3L, 5L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 
    8L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 
    5L, 0L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 5L, 
    7L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 3L, 3L), Tea_Cups = c(2L, 
    4L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 0L, 
    2L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
    0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    Mins_Work = c(435L, 350L, 145L, 135L, 15L, 60L, 60L, 390L, 
    395L, 395L, 315L, 80L, 580L, 175L, 545L, 230L, 435L, 370L, 
    255L, 515L, 330L, 65L, 115L, 550L, 420L, 45L, 266L, 196L, 
    198L, 220L, 17L, 382L, 0L, 180L, 343L, 207L, 263L, 332L, 
    0L, 0L, 259L, 417L, 282L, 685L, 517L, 111L, 64L, 466L, 499L, 
    460L, 269L, 300L, 427L, 301L, 436L, 342L, 229L, 379L, 102L, 
    146L, 94L, 345L, 73L, 204L, 512L, 113L, 135L, 458L, 493L, 
    552L, 108L, 335L, 395L, 508L, 546L, 396L, 159L, 325L, 747L, 
    650L, 377L, 461L, 669L, 186L, 220L, 410L, 708L, 409L, 515L, 
    413L)), row.names = c(NA, -90L), class = "data.frame")
```

## Script for Markdown:

```
# Load libaries:    
library(tidyverse) # piping and general ggplot functions
library(ggpubr) # better looking ggplots
library(plotly) # interactive plots
library(foreign) # loading most types of data

# Load dataset:
work <- read.csv("Shawn_Productivity.csv") %>% 
  slice(1:113) 

work_clean <- work %>% 
  filter(!Month_Name == "December") %>% 
  filter(!Mins_Work=="NA")

# Full Boxplot:
gbox <- ggboxplot(work_clean,
          x = "Day_Name",
          y = "Mins_Work",
          color = "Day_Name",
          palette = "futurama") +
  labs(x="Day Name",
       y="Minutes of Work",
       title = "ANOVA Boxplot of Daily Differences in Productivity")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold"),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "gray"),
        axis.text = element_text(color = "black"),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(face = "italic"))+
  annotate("text",
           x=5.5,
           y=700,
           label = "*No overall or PWC significance found")

ggplotly(gbox)

# Create interactive plot:
ggplotly(gbox)
```

Which should give me this interactive plot in R:

[image]

## Error

Instead what I get is this error message:

```
Line 9: Error in file (file, "rt") : ?????????
Calls: <Anonymous> ... eval -> %>% -> slice -> read.csv -> read.table -> file
???
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

What do I do to fix this? I've tried nitpicking the code, using the exact directory name for the CSV file, etc. to see whats wrong but cant seem to find the error.

For clarification, this is what the R Markdown doc looks like:

````
---
title: "Using GGPLOTLY for Interactive Plots"
author: "Shawn Hemelstrand"
date: "2021/12/23"
output: html_document
---

```{r interactive, echo=TRUE}
# Load libraries:
library(tidyverse) # piping and general ggplot functions
library(ggpubr) # better looking ggplots
library(plotly) # interactive plots
library(foreign) # loading most types of data
library(rstatix) # for ANOVA functions

# Load dataset:
work <- read.csv("Shawn_Productivity.csv") %>% 
  slice(1:113) 

work_clean <- work %>% 
  filter(!Month_Name == "December") %>% 
  filter(!Mins_Work=="NA")

# Full Boxplot:
gbox <- ggboxplot(work_clean,
          x = "Day_Name",
          y = "Mins_Work",
          color = "Day_Name",
          palette = "futurama") +
  labs(x="Day Name",
       y="Minutes of Work",
       title = "ANOVA Boxplot of Daily Differences in Productivity")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold"),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "gray"),
        axis.text = element_text(color = "black"),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(face = "italic"))+
  annotate("text",
           x=5.5,
           y=700,
           label = "*No overall or PWC significance found")

ggplotly(gbox)
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know the current directory before executing the code. You can get it using `getwd()`.

The working directory of your R console and the working directory of the `R markdown` file that you have created is different.

R markdown documents are compiled separately in separate R sessions. So your, current R console has nothing to do with the compilation of the R markdown documents.

Once, you get the current working directory with `getwd()`. You need to change it with the correct path where your `R markdown` file is saved using `setwd()`.

**EDIT**
The only thing I did different that your code is as follows:

```
setwd("D:/Programming/StackOverflow/")
work <- read.csv("Shawn_Productivity.csv") %>% 
  slice(1:113)
```

Comment: As I mentioned before, I already checked the WD. I even used setwd() with the directory in the markdown, but it doesnt allow me to knit it still.

Comment: Please include your data using `dput` to recreate the problem.

Comment: Just edited the post with the dput included. Thanks!

Comment: What is `tukey_work_day`? I'm getting error saying object `object 'tukey_work_day' not found`

Comment: Oh that was another tukey test I ran with the following:
``tukey_work_day <- work_clean %>% 
  tukey_hsd(Mins_Work ~ Day_Name)``

Comment: I'm still getting errors in your code. Here's another one: ```Error in .valide_y_position(y.position, data) : can't find the y.position variable 'y.position' in the data```

Comment: I think I see what is going on. Lemme check really quick.

Comment: I've decided to delete all of the unnecessary rstatix stuff but it didnt change anything. I've edited my post above to reflect this.

Comment: I ran the code you have provided and successfully knitted the document without any issues.

Comment: I dont know what happened but this time when I reset R, reentered the WD, then ran the doc, it suddenly worked. I'm going to accept your answer since its what was the cause of the issue. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Its okay it already seemed to work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad it worked!